# springboot jsp twitter-bootstrap sitemesh rendering - "on - off" (when refresh in Firefox) - why?

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple web-app with springboot, jsps, and twitter-bootstrap. In localhost, Firefox:
Strangely; when I open the page - no css-rendering. 'click' onto refresh in the browser, it is rendered (twitter bt). click again, not rendered ..
If someone please gave me hint about that, and what to do with it (what is it, that I did not correctly?)

Comment: In which folders are your jsps located, and in which folder your css file?

Comment: Hello @Glorfindel, webapp/resources/css/...css; WEB-INF/decorators/bootstrap.jsp (referring to the css); WEB-INF/views/[other].jsp.